# Cannot connect to database with PDO

Tags: php, pdo

I've got the following code:

```
try {
    $db = new PDO('mysql:host=127.0.0.1;db=example', 'root', '');
    $db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

    $stmt = $db->query('SELECT * FROM posts');


} catch (PDOException $e) {

    echo $db->errorCode();
    var_dump($db->errorInfo());

}
```

And I get the following error:

```
3D000array(3) { [0]=> string(5) "3D000" [1]=> int(1046) [2]=> string(20) "No database selected" }
```

However, this ONLY occurs when I include `$stmt = $db->query('SELECT * FROM posts');`

This is my first time with PDO, Would anyone know why this is not working? The database and table exist.

Comment: is database `example` exist? You should write database name at `example`

Comment: Try with localhost instead of 172.0.0.1

Comment: should $stmt = $db->query('SELECT * FROM posts'); be something like $stmt = $db->prepare('SELECT * FROM posts');

Comment: @Satya query and prepare are both valid

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have:

```
db=example
```

You need:

```
dbname=example
```

Sadly, there's no way to get an error message or notification of any kind if you mistype a DSN parameter.

Available parameters are documented at [PDO_MYSQL DSN](https://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-mysql.connection.php).

Answer (score 0):

dname and not only db

```
try {
    $db = new PDO('mysql:host=127.0.0.1;dbname=example', 'root', '');
    $db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

    $stmt = $db->query('SELECT * FROM posts');


} catch (PDOException $e) {

    echo $db->errorCode();
    var_dump($db->errorInfo());

}
```

http://www.php.net/manual/fr/book.pdo.php